# Custom Camel Component - calling FTP within an FTP Consumer

Tags: apache-camel

I am attempting to create a custom Camel component.

It is for an old system that communicates with FTP (holds a conversation with files for want of a better description).  My consumer therefore extends `FtpConsumer`.
It will poll for files, which works fine.

What I then need to do is create another FTP connection - technically to the same machine, but a different path.
In my experiments, I have used a Consumer Template with a constructed URI to go and get me another file (based on the content of the polled file).

This has worked at a high level and grabs the file I need.
Can anyone confirm if this is a dangerous thing to do?

As per the documentation:

> The FTP consumer (with the same endpoint) does not support concurrency (the backing FTP client is not thread safe).
>   You can use multiple FTP consumers to poll from different endpoints. It is only a single endpoint that does not support concurrent consumers.

Could this have repercussions here?
Is there a better way of making this secondary FTP connection?  Especially a safer way.

Of course, the file I want does get retrieved, and I can pass this further into the Camel route, however, I am seeing issues when I get down to byte-level processing (bitwise calculations etc) when working on an FTP streamed file, and I am wondering if this is to do with it.

*So I suppose my main question is, what is the safe Camel way to call multiple FTP commands as I've described within a single consumer?*

If what I am doing should work, then maybe I need a new question regarding my bitwise operations on this data (basically, they always work fine as long as only a single FTP get is made - I.e. the consumer runs the process on the polled file.  But if I poll for a file, then use that to get another file, that file processing fails at the low level - as if there are memory/threading issues).

Comment: I'm having the same issue at work too - I'd be interested to hear any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

To establish another FTP connection (same machine, different path), you may use [pollEnrich](https://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) in your route.

---

> The FTP consumer (with the same endpoint) does not support concurrency (the backing FTP client is not thread safe). You can use multiple FTP consumers to poll from different endpoints. It is only a single endpoint that does not support concurrent consumers.

This part is stating if you have multiple FTP consumer point to same endpoint (i.e. same machine, same path). They will potentially compete same file and result in duplicate/incomplete/empty file consumed.

Comment: Can Camel Routes be created inside of Components?  Or is there another method to do something like pollEnrich within a Component?  I thought Producer and Consumer templates were about the only thing I can create inside of a Component (that is already within the Camel context) - I'm hoping I'm wrong and there is an easy way I've not noticed yet.

Comment: You can create route by route builder. There is no method in FTP component to do things like pollEnrich. What you want to attempt can be done by route, why component?

Comment: The component is to wrap a custom protocol that the route builders will know nothing about.  For example S3 does things differently under the covers than HTTP - so they have an S3 component.  We have a protocol based on FTP that needs to do different things under the covers.  We need to supply the component so route builders can use it - so we are working at a level below the 'route'.
The more I dig, the more I am thinking that Consumer Templates might well be fine to use for this circumstance.

Comment: Use Consumer Templates within custom component may leave the delete/move operation of another file not under control. An alternative way to do is complete the task within one single connection (i.e. do another relative path moving and collect file)